# Determinants over commutative rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Hello, I am preparing a paper on determinants in commutative rings. Someone can give me examples of applications of determinants in commutative rings to other areas of mathematics or physics. Thank you

Comment: This seems a bit of an unspecific request. What type of paper? Original research, a survey, or something for a course, say? In addition, do you want applications where the ring is actually not a field, or more narrowly not the reals or complex numbers. Or  would applciations for them also be fine; they are comm rings after all.

Comment: The paper is on the convertion the determinant into the permanent. Yes i want applications where the ring has zero divisors. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would this be an example of what you are looking for?

**Definition.** We say that an element $f$ of a local ring $R$ is a determinant if $f$ is the determinant of some $n\times n$ matrix, $n\geq2$ with entries in the maximal ideal of $R$.

**Theorem (Eisenbud).** *Let $R$ be a $3$-dimensional regular local ring, and let $f\in R$ be a prime element. Then the quotient ring $R/(f)$ is factorial if and only if $f$ is not a determinant in $R$.*

**Reference.**

The previous theorem can be found on page 124 of:

Eisenbud, D.: *[Recent progress in commutative algebra](http://www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1975-002.pdf)*, Algebraic geometry - Arcata 1974, AMS Proc. of Pure Math. **XXIX** (1975), 111-128.